# Android Listview ontop of another class

Tags: android, list, listview

I know how to write an app that solely uses android's listview, but how would I integrate my listview class into another class?

Since java cannot extend more than one class, I'm stumped as to how this would be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to integrate listview class into Activity class, you can use ListActivity class.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your own WyattsListView that extends ListView then you can use your WyattsListView any place that you would otherwise use a regular ListView.

[This](http://androidtut.blog.com/listview/) page gives a simple example of how you can create an activity that only has one ListView UI element. Simply Instantiate WyattsListView instead of a regular ListView.